# Sending more than one file via Python Socket

Tags: python, file, sockets

I'm making a file transfer program and maneged to make it work for one file, but when I try to send more than that it does not work.

Here's the server's code:

```
import socket
import os
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import filedialog as fd

SERVER = socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname())
PORT = 1234
HEADER = 10

WINDOW_X = 600
WINDOW_Y = 350

root = tk.Tk()
root.title('MyCoolProgram')
root.resizable(False, False)
root.geometry(f'{WINDOW_X}x{WINDOW_Y}')

print(f'Binding {SERVER} with port {PORT}...')
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.bind((SERVER, PORT))

print(f'Listening...')
s.listen(5)

def send(files):
    con, addr = s.accept()
    print('Connected with ', addr)
    filedata = b''
    for file in files:

        head, tail = os.path.split(file)
        os.chdir(head)
        
        filename = tail
        filename = f'{len(filename):<{HEADER}}' + filename
        con.send(filename.encode())

        filesize = os.stat(tail).st_size
        filesize = f'{filesize:<{HEADER}}'
        filesize = filesize.encode()

        with open(tail, 'rb') as f:
            content = f.read()
            
        filedata += filesize + content + '\0'

        con.send(filedata)

        con.close()
    


files = ''
T = tk.Text(root, height=18, width=73)
T.place(x=5, y=10)
T.config(state='disabled')

def openfiles(): 
    global files
    files = fd.askopenfilenames(parent=root, title='Escolha arquivos para serem enviados')

    T.config(state='normal')

    for file in files:
        T.insert('end',file + '\n')

    T.config(state='disabled')

def sendloop():
    global files
    send(files)
        

open_files_button = tk.Button(root, command=openfiles, text="Selecionar arquivos", height=2, padx=7)
open_files_button.place(x=WINDOW_X - 130 , y = WINDOW_Y - 45)

send_files_button = tk.Button(root, command=sendloop, text="Enviar", height=2, padx=27)
send_files_button.place(x=WINDOW_X - 230 , y = WINDOW_Y - 45)

root.mainloop()
```

*Note: The Tkinter it's kinda goofy, but it serves its porpouse of grabbing the PATH of selected files.*

Here's the client's code:

```
import socket
import tqdm

HEADER = 10 
SERVER = "SERVER's PUBLIC IP" #on the 'working' code, it is the actual ip
BUFFER = 1024

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.connect((SERVER, 1234))

print(f'Conectado a {SERVER}.')

while True:
    full_data = b''
    new = True

    name_data = []


    while True:
        data = s.recv(BUFFER)


        if new:
            
            datalen = int(data[:HEADER])
            new = False
            progress = tqdm.tqdm(unit='B',unit_scale=True, unit_divisor=1000, total=int(datalen))
            


        full_data += data

        progress.update(BUFFER)

        if len(full_data)-HEADER == datalen:
            acc_data = full_data[HEADER:]
            name_data.append(acc_data)
            new = True
            full_data = b''


        if len(name_data) == 2:
            with open(name_data[0], 'wb') as f:
                f.write(name_data[1])
            print(f'{name_data[0]} recieved' )

            name_data = []
            new = True
            full_data = b''
```

What I'm currently doing is holding the name of the file and its byte contents in *name_data[]* and when the packet is recieved, it creates the file and writes its bytes.

As stated before, this works for a single file but not for multiple.

As a beguinner in python sockets I do not know how to aproach sending multiple things. So any help will be wanted!

*Note: The server is sending the files to the client as it made more sense for me in this project*

Comment: `datalen = int(data[:HEADER])` ... what happens if `recv()` only returns 5 bytes instead of 10+?

Comment: @PresidentJamesK.Polk, that bit of code is inside the `if new` bit, which means it should be a new message, and every new message starts with a 10 bit header. So i should not ever get less than 10 bits. That's the idea at least.

Comment: TCP is not message-based.  Do not expect any recv to be a specific number of bytes. Buffer data until you have the exact size expected

Comment: @MarkTolonen could you give me a code exemple of that ?

Comment: See the duplicate.

Answer (score -2):

> As a beguinner in python sockets I do not know how to aproach sending
> multiple things. So any help will be wanted!

I suggest following approach

1. create archive, e.g. .zip file holding required files
2. send it - you have already implemented that as archive is single file
3. unpack archive

as python standard library has [`zipfile`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/zipfile.html) you do not have to use any external dependency if you elect to use zip format.

Comment: That would work for this particular project, but I still wanna learn how to send multiple actual files. Thank you for the input though!